# NSAlert not working in an image capture extension

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an application that is an ica driver for image capture application. I am trying to show a alert box, but i am facing a problem. Below mentioned is the code i am using to display the alert box.

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init ] ;
[ alert setTextMessage:@"test" ];
[ alert runModal ] ;
```

When running the app in MAC 10.6 , the alert box is displayed. However on MAC 10.7 and above the alert box is not displayed and the main application window stays in the blocked mode and no operation can be performed on it. Can you please guide me how to get this resolved.

Comment: Did you try `– beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:` instead?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do this? My code runs as an extension of the main application in the form of a library.

Comment: See Apple's docs, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAlertSheets.html

Comment: I do not have a main application window object to work with in this function. I need to use an application-modal window in this case, hence the above mentioned approach. This piece of code works fine with 10.6 mac osx. I have a problem running this "runModal" function in 10.7 and later. Has something changed with the usage i am not aware of?